# ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST adds more id's then available records

Tags: mysql

With Sql ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST I add a auto increment column to an existing table with 100000 records in phpmyadmin, at first glance the incremental numbers seem correct, 1,2,3,4 and so on.

However when looking at the last records in the table there are more id's then records!?

e.g. with 100000 records there are 101234 id's

What could be the issue?

[image: added double PK]

Comment: what version are you on select version() and what do you get when you select count(*) from <yourtable>?

Comment: If a transaction with insert fails, for any reason, any generated id's will not be used and will be lost. This is 'normal'.

Comment: @P.Salmon version is 5.7.29-32-log

SQL select count(`id`) FROM `mag_productsImport_fr` returns the exact number of records that are in the table.

Comment: And what is that exact number?

Comment: in this table are a total of 12979 records.
the highest id is 13025.

it seems that ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST is skipping incrementals some how, need to eyeball table where it's skipped numbers

Comment: as a matter of interest did your table have a primary key before you added?

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT guarantees that each next generated value is greater than previous one. But it does not guarantee the values adjacency. If you want to obtain adjacent values you must create common column, fill it with adjacent values with according query, then make this column AI PK.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, it has. That could be causing the issue? 

Before the table is filled with data it's created based on an existing table that has a primairy key already (CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE table_template)

Will do a try adding a the AI column whit out existing PK

Comment: I doubt it given there is no requirement for auto_increment column to either a primary or unique key. But you are adding an auto_increment column to a table and since tables have no inherent order the addition of an auto_increment column may not number in a way which resembles your previous (assumed) table order. If you do want that then you should add a column numbering it yourself before modifying to auto_increment.

Comment: @P.Salmon removing the PK before adding the new AI column did the job :) Now the number of records matches the incrementas correctly

Answer (score 0):

Like other people suggested, adjecency is not warranted when adding AI attribute for a column. Therefore, manual intervention should be execised. Assuming your current PK column is of int type and it's named pk_id and your newly added column is called id, we can use a cursor in a loop to fetch each pk_id and update its associated id accordingly:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists add_ai//

CREATE  PROCEDURE add_ai()
begin
declare n int default 1;
declare c_pk_id int;
declare fin bool default false;
declare c cursor for select pk_id from yourtable;
declare continue handler for not found set fin=true;

open c;
lp: loop
fetch c into c_pk_id;

if fin=true then
leave lp;
end if;

update yourtable set id=n where pk_id=c_pk_id;
set n=n+1;
end loop lp;

end//
```